# Baby monitor for outdoor use?

Tags: infant, newborn, safety, outdoor

There are tons of baby monitors when searching on Google, but when adding the restriction that it has to also work for outdoor use, I can't find a single one.

The baby unit have to work from -5ºC degrees.

**Question**

Does such exist in normal shops, or does there exist a special brand, that fulfills this need?

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic here, but if you can provide more detail on your intended usage we may be able to direct you to other products which are not specifically baby monitors that can meet your needs.  Also if you let us know your region as they have different radio/wireless rules.

Comment: if the baby is in -5, presumably you have something keeping the baby warm? So put the unit in with the baby!

Comment: Do the units you look at specifically state they DO NOT work when it is cold? Because I would assume that most baby monitors would work in a pram or similar you place outside. I have many friends in countries where it is common for babies to sleep in their pram outside, and the monitors people use there seem pretty normal to me, they just place them next to the baby's head in the pram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ida makes a good point! In general most commercial electronics are good a little bit below zero. Battery life starts to go down, as batteries are adversely affected by cold, but the circuits themselves should be okay. They tend to be more affected by water...

But remember - if you have it next to your baby, it will end up around the same temperature as them (or at least near it) so if your baby can cope, I'd assume the monitor can.

Answer (score 0):

There are baby monitor apps you can install on two smartphones, one becomes the monitor and the other the receiver. If you had two smartphones that work in the necessary conditions, that could work.   I haven't used these apps enough to make any specific recommendation.

Also, you could keep a phone in an inside pocket to keep it warmer than the surrounding air, which might also be helpful.

If this is for camping or other outdoor type activities, it might be a relevant question on the "outdoors" stack exchange site.